# In D3, how to use SVG files as DOM objects with bound data and paths still exposed?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

This is a problem that I was having, and solved, which seemed useful enough to share, at least because I suspect I will have the problem again.

---

## Issue: Read in SVG image *and expose its path elements*

Create scatterplot **points** which are actually cute, little SVG images from files, **with the SVG paths exposed**. The interest in D3.js is at least partly due to its "infinite flexibility", and if I wanted just a simple plot, there are easier ways than D3.

This means:

- I wanted to be able to read in the image from an SVG file.
- I still wanted to be able to access the SVG paths.  In this case, I wanted to be able to adjust the line thicknesses of lines in the logo, based upon bound data (similar to how we might adjust the circle radius based upon data).

Any way that I tried to do this importing the svg file as an image, for instance via `<selection>.append('svg:image')` or something similar, *did not expose the SVG path details*.

---

I solved this, and I am posting my solution below, in hopes of helping others.

Comment: Is this any different from [*"d3 - Append elements to external SVG file"*](/q/20233826)? Also, there is Mike Bostock's [*External SVG*](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1014829) Block.

Comment: @altocumulus Yes, it is different from both of them.  The former **does not expose the HTML**.  Why is that important?  I wanted to be able to adjust path thicknesses, so I needed the SVG's paths exposed.  The latter *does expose the HTML*, but it does this in HTML, instead of in SVG.  So, the latter is like 90% of the way there, but here I am going that last 10%.  It might be obvious to some people, but it was not initially obvious to me, until I played around with it for a while.

Comment: Maybe I don't get what you are after, but both examples do exactly the same thing by using `document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);` to append the external SVG to the document's body. From that on the SVG's DOM is accessible—i.e. exposed, if you will—for further manipulation. Also, `selection.html()` wasn't meant to handle the SVG namespace, although it should nowadays be capable of. Have a look at my [answer](/a/38072166/4235784) to [*"D3 append HTML not working in edge browser"*](/q/38064765) plus the comments to that for further details. Anyways, good, if it helped you out.

Comment: @altocumulus Yes, you don't quite get what I am after.  The external SVG file that I am pulling in ***is being treated as a DOM object to attach data to***.  Think of having scatterplot points, where each point is actually a pretty SVG file pulled in.  Using `document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement)` does not achieve this, as it is pulling the SVG element into the HTML space.  I instead want (1) the element pulled into the larger SVG that is the plot figure area, and (2) more importantly, I want to be able to ***bind data to it***.  My solution achieves these 2 things.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution: `d3.xml` plus `d3.queue`

I needed to set up a `d3.queue`, where one external call was bringing in the data for the visualization, and the other was bringing in the SVG image mentioned above.

The entire visualization became fairly large and complex; the code below captures the relevant parts as I'd used them.

```
// First create helper function with callback return, to provide structure `d3.queue` needs.
readSvg = function(svg_path, callback) {
  d3.xml(svg_path).mimeType("image/svg+xml")
    .get(function(err, xml) {
       if (err) {
         throw err;
       }
       callback(null, xml.documentElement.outerHTML);
     });
};

// Next make the `d3.queue` call.
// (In reality, the `makeViz` function would need to be defined first, but
//  logically, I felt it easier to understand if I show this first.)
d3.queue()
  .defer(readSvg, my_svg_image_path)
  .defer(d3.json, my_data_path)
  .await(makeViz);


// "Finally" display the visualizations using `makeViz`.
var makeViz = function(error, svg_image, data) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    var points = svg.selectAll('.point')
                    .data(data).enter()
                    .append('g')
                    .classed('point', true)
                    .style('fill', my_fill)
                    .style('stroke-opacity', my_opacity)
                    .html(svg_image); // Note the `html` call!!!
    // These circles are added to make the icons more easily "clickable".
    // NOTE:  THE VARIABLE "points" IS STILL ASSOCIATED WITH THE IMAGE, NOT
    //        THE CIRCLES BELOW!!!  THIS IS ON PURPOSE, FOR EASIER
    //        ASSOCIATION AND MAPPING LATER!!
    points.append('circle').attr('r', icon_size);
    // Now call a function that associates all of the x & y coordinates according
    // to the bound data and what the users click on.  (`clicked` is a variable
    // defined out of scope, and is part of the interactivity.)
    updatePoints(data, points, clicked);
```

---

A few things to note:

1. The image had a lot of "empty space".  Imagine if the image were a smiley face; most of the smiley face is nothing.  Therefore, most of it is **not clickable**.  I therefore created a parent `g` DOM element and attached the circle to it as well as the image.  Therefore, the entire "smiley face" was clickable, including the white space.
2. By using this `d3.xml.mimeType.get` call, I was able to get the entire SVG structure of the file.  Then sending on its `.documentElement.outerHTML` gave me just the parts I was looking for: all of the `g`s, `svg`s, `path`s, and all other elements of the image, and none of the other DOM stuff that comes along with an `xml` import.
3. Because I needed to import 2 things, I needed to use `d3.queue`.  But because `d3.queue` works via an expected callback, I needed to structure that skeleton call with `readSvg` as I did.  That function does not do much, except call the function that is passed to it, which is a function to return the data.

   - There might be a better or cleaner way to handle this part, but simply making a `d3.xml` call directly within `d3.queue` I could not get to work properly.

---

If anyone has better suggestions, that's great, but I can say this works.

Also, I'm always looking for tips, pointers, and suggestions for how to indent all these chained calls.  Is the way I've shown here the best?  I find it challenging to read `d3` code sometimes because of the combination of chained calls and callback functions.  (I'm in the process of adopting an `async/await` structure for some of my `d3` work.)

Comment: Thanks Mike. However, I tried this with multiple `svg` paths but it doesn't work. Example:
    `svgData.forEach(function(d) {
        d3.queue()
          .defer(readSvg, d);
      });
      d3.queue()
        .awaitAll(function(error, svgPaths) {
          if (error) throw error;
          console.log(svgPaths);
        });`

Comment: @Markus I am not *exactly* sure what the problem is with your construct, as I did not try to replicate it.  However, my guess would be that `d3.queue()` is not allowed within the `svgData.forEach` method. `d3.queue()` allows for tasks to be thrown on the [event queue](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-js-the-event-loop-959beae3ac40), in fact that's its main point.  My guess is that the functions which can be passed to these callbacks cannot themselves be functions that add to that event queue. I would presume they need to be something which can be immediately calculated. Anyone know??